# spotify models.Track object

Tags: spotify

is the spotify models.Track object restricted to non-local tracks only?

I've built a little spotify app that will calculate the total play time of some random assortment of tracks that are dropped into the sidebar, but it seems like the Track object doesn't get any information from local files.

Here's what I got so far:

```
models.application.observe(models.EVENT.LINKSCHANGED, function () {
    totalTime = 0;
    var links = models.application.links;
    if (links.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            var track = models.Track.fromURI(links[i], function(t) {
                totalTime = totalTime + t.duration;
            });
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = secondsToString(Math.round(totalTime/1000))  ;
});
```

Everything is firing correctly and working great on spotify tracks, but the whole reason i wrote this little app was so that I could calculate the total time of some of my really long audiobook files.  Anyone know of a solution?

[Link to the documentation page](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/4f52ebf870.html).

Answer (score 0):

If this is indeed the case, I think you've found a bug/oversight.

However, local file URIs look like this: `spotify:local:Coldplay:Mylo+Xyloto:Paradise:277`

That last parameter is the length of the track, in integral seconds. It's a hacky workaround, but you could parse the URI and use the figure from that instead of `models.Track`.